# Why is this code giving segmentation fault?

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program that takes any number of one-word text string arguments, each less than 128 characters long. The program copies text from stdin to stdout, except that any of the words seen in the input are replaced with the word "CENSORED".

Example:
I have this file called poem.txt:

```
Said Hamlet to Ophelia,
I'll draw a sketch of thee,
What kind of pencil shall I use?
2B or not 2B?
```

The program should do this:

```
./censor Ophelia < poem.txt
Said Hamlet to CENSORED,
I'll draw a sketch of thee,
What kind of pencil shall I use?
2B or not 2B?
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char lines[200][200];
    int numLines=0,i,j;
    int nbytes = 128;
    int bytes_read=0;
    char *my_string;
    char * pch;
    //reading from stdin
    while(stdin)
    {
    my_string=(char *) malloc (nbytes + 1);
    bytes_read = getline (&my_string, &nbytes, stdin);  
    strcpy(lines[numLines++],my_string);
    }

    //scanning and replacing specified words by "CENSORED"
    for(i=0;i<argc;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<numLines;j++)
        {   
             pch = strstr (lines[j],argv[i]);
             strncpy (pch,"CENSORED",8);
        }
    }
    //display the result in output screen
    for(j=0;j<numLines;j++)
        {
            printf("\n%s",lines[i]);
        }

}
```

The problem is that this is giving segmentation fault, but I can't identify the mistake.

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Look at the definition of `argc` and `argv`. BTW, you should detail where the seg-fault occurred

Comment: `while(stdin)` what do you think it would do? Does `stdin` ever becomes 0 ??

Comment: also check the two lines wrt. `pch`, what if `strstr` returns NULL? what would happen with the line below it (ie `strncpy`)?

Comment: `strstr()` can return `NULL`, if it doesn't find the string being searched for - and passing a `NULL` pointer to `strncpy()` gives undefined behaviour.   The first loop also has a memory leak.  Memory allocated using `malloc()` is only released during program execution by a call to `free()` or `realloc()`, and your code uses neither.

Comment: Most popular C question ever... :D

Comment: @artm nailed the issue. In your code `while(stdin)` never becomes `0` as `EOF` is generally defined as (`-1`) which tests `true`.

Comment: in C, do not cast the returned value from any of the heap memory allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc).   The returned type from the heap memory allocation functions is `void*`, so can be assigned to any other pointer.   Casting just clutters the code making it much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain.

Comment: The parameter passed to `malloc()` should be of type `long unsigned int`.  The posted code is passing an `int`.  This causes the compiler to output a warning message about possible modification of the value,.

Comment: when compiling, always enable all the warnings, then fix those warnings,  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -std=gnu99`  I also use: `-Wconversion` and to make it easy to use the `gdb` debugger I use: `-ggdb`

Comment: When you have the code cleanly compiling (and there are currently several problems raised by the compiler) then (and only then) should you be trying to run the code

Comment: for ease of readability and understand, by us humans, 1) follow the axiom: `only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.`  2) consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'. unindent before every closing brace '}'.  3) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line.

Comment: the function: `getline()` returns a `ssize_t`, not an `int`.   The second parameter to `getline()` is a `size_t`, not an `int`.  Strongly suggest reading/understanding the man page for each system function that the posted code uses.

Comment: when calling system functions (in this case `malloc()` and `getline()` and `strstr()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the variable `bytes_read` is set but not used.  (it should have been used for checking if the call to `getline()` was successful.)

Comment: the statement: `while(stdin)` is useless, as `stdin` never changes.  Strongly suggest using the call to `getline()` to control the loop  AND do not pre-allocate the lines[][] array because the code, normally, does not know how many lines will be read.    Suggest scan each line as it is read for the bad word(s) and immediately output the line,  then NO `lines` array needed.

Comment: the current code will destroy ALL of a input line starting with the 'bad' word,  That is probably NOT what you really want to do,  What if the input line was: "my bad word", then if `bad` was the word to be replaced with:`censored`,  then the new line would look like: "my censored"  which is not what you want.  Suggest, have a 'work' line, array of char.  Then copy, up to the bad word to the output, then output the 'censored' then output the rest of the line after the 'bad' word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not properly overwritting a hit with the replacement which might be longer or shorter -- you're just stuffing it in regardless (potentially overwriting the terminal `\0`, possibly leading to your segmentation fault).  Also, it looks like you miss double hits as you only check each command line word once against each line.  Finally, you've made this more complicated by storing all the lines -- no line affects any other so why store them rather than process and print each line in turn?

Here's a overall simplified approach with more detailed replacement code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define REPLACEMENT "CENSORED"
#define BUFFER_SIZE (1024)

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ssize_t bytes_read;
    char *s, *line = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
    size_t nbytes = BUFFER_SIZE, replacement_length = strlen(REPLACEMENT);

    // read from stdin
    while ((bytes_read = getline(&line, &nbytes, stdin)) != -1)
    {  
        // scanning and replacing specified words
        for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
        {
            while ((s = strstr(line, argv[i])) != NULL)
            {
                size_t search_length = strlen(argv[i]);
                size_t tail_length = strlen(s + search_length);

                (void) memmove(s + replacement_length, s + search_length, tail_length + 1);
                (void) memcpy(s, REPLACEMENT, replacement_length);
            }
        }

        // display the result in output screen
        (void) fputs(line, stdout);
    }

    free(line);
}
```

Oh yeah, and you forgot to *free* what you *malloc'd*.  And you're searching for the name of the program as one of your targets...

**EXAMPLE**

```
> ./a.out pencil 2B < poem.txt
Said Hamlet to Ophelia,
I'll draw a sketch of thee,
What kind of CENSORED shall I use?
CENSORED or not CENSORED?
```

Comment: How do you insure the replacement of `argv[i]` with `REPLACEMENT` in `line` does not exceed the default allocation of `line` by `getline` -- thereby writing beyond the end of `line`? (e.g. if line is `"'115 chars' 2B"` and you replace `2B` with `CENSORED`. you overwrite the end of the `120-byte` default allocation of `line` by `5`) [**see GNU glibc iogetdelim.c**](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=libio/iogetdelim.c;h=50fda58e6832d23391d26d3c64c7b66b11d304c3;hb=release/2.23/master)

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Rankin, that was a total goof.  One that C is happy to let me make.  I've put a minimal bandaid on it, allocating a static buffer 5x the size the OP estimated for this problem.  Sigh.

Comment: I like your answer, that was the only thing that caught my eye. Good job. (you could also check the length of each line + the difference caused by any replacement and allocate a tmp buffer if it exceed the value of `'n'` used with `getline`.) (you can also pass a larger `'n'` to `getline`)

Comment: Better to pass a couple of pointers to `getline()` so that the `getline()` function allocates the needed memory,